# Why isn't my class method recognized?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I am trying to understand why my class method was not recognized. Below is my code:

wiki_patch.rb

```
require_dependency 'wiki_content'

module WikiRecipientPatch
    def self.included(base)
      base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)

      base.class_eval do
        alias_method_chain :recipients, :send_wiki_mail
      end
    end
end

module InstanceMethods
    def self.set_mail_checker(mail)
      @mail_checker = mail
    end
end

Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  WikiContent.send(:include, WikiRecipientPatch)
end
```

controller.rb

```
WikiContent.set_mail_checker(params[:mail_checker_wiki])
```

I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `set_mail_checker' for #<Class:0x4876560>):
```

Any idea why it happens and what the solution for it is?

Answer (score 1):

You got the idiom slightly wrong.

1. `ClassMethods`/`InstanceMethods` modules are supposed to be nested in the "main" module (`WikiRecipientPatch` in this case).
2. You are including instance methods, but expecting class methods to somehow arise from this? Surely you meant `extend ClassMethods`, didn't you?

   ```
   module WikiRecipientPatch
     def self.included(base)
       base.extend ClassMethods
     end

     module ClassMethods
       def set_mail_checker(mail)
         'mail checker'
       end
     end
   end

   class WikiContent; end

   WikiContent.send(:include, WikiRecipientPatch)

   WikiContent.set_mail_checker('whatever') # => "mail checker"
   ```

Comment: Using your tip I got the following error: `NoMethodError (undefined method `set_mail_checker' for InstanceMethods::WikiContent:Class)`. I did something wrong?

Comment: @user2195342, yes, likely. Because the code in the answer works.

Comment: I forgot to mention there is 2 methods inside my module. One of these methods is included by module. The other is the listed above. I hid the other just to simplify the question.